# inserting demo data in hibernate without the primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

i am using hibernate 3 and PostgreSQL database
and i am trying to insert demo data in hibernate import.sql file without inserting the primary key

```
insert into AUTHORITY (NAME, DISPLAY_NAME, DESCRIPTION,IS_DEFAULT) values ('ROLE_USER', 'Role User', 'accessing user',true);
```

and i define the id as follows:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "authority_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private long id;
```

i am getting following exception:

```
org.hibernate.JDBCException: Error during import script execution at line 2
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.importScript(SchemaExport.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "authority_id" violates not-null constraint
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1525)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1309)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:188)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:452)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:340)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.importScript(SchemaExport.java:328)
    ... 43 more
```

why it's not working, and the id is not getting generated automatically, and how to fix that, thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Don't create your own insert query, create a bean and use session.save() method to save it.

Comment: @ManuPK, i am making demo data.

Comment: @Jigar Joshi exception added to post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres you should insert the primary key. Just do like this:

```
insert into AUTHORITY (ID, NAME, DISPLAY_NAME, DESCRIPTION,IS_DEFAULT) values (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), 'ROLE_USER', 'Role User', 'accessing user',true);
```

, where `hibernate_sequence` is a default name of sequence, which hibernate creates, you could have something else.

Comment: i found only one sequence in the database called hibernate_sequence, that's it ?

Comment: Yes. Updated my answer to mention the `hibernate_sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also insert fixed numbers (i do it to make teh FK to other tables) and in the end of your import.sql add a command to alter your sequence. Like this (postgres sintax):

```
insert into person values (1, 'John');
insert into person values (2, 'Pedro');
insert into person values (3, 'Junior');
ALTER SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence RESTART WITH 15;
```